# object oriented programming with tamagotchi class

Tags: python

Write a class `Tamagotchi` that creates a Tamagotchi object with the specified name. You should decide what properties the `Tamagotchi` object should have in order to support the required behaviour as elaborated below. A `Tamagotchi` object, t has three methods:

- `teach` where there can be a variable number of string inputs. This teaches the tamagotchi these words. Symbols will also work. If you try to teach a tamagotchi the same words more than once, it will ignore the later attempts.
- `play` will make the tamagotchi return a stringified list of words that it has been taught (in sequential order).
- `kill` will kill the tamagotchi. Once a tamagotchi is in heaven, it cannot be taught and will not respond when you try to play with it. Instead, all further method calls will return the string `"<name> is pining for the fjords"` where `<name>` is the name of the tamagotchi.

This is my code:

```
class Tamagotchi():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def teach(self, words):
        new_words = []
        [new_words.append(x) for x in words if x not in new_words]
        ("".join(new_words))

    def play(self):
        return 'meow meow says ' + Tamogotchi.teach(words)
```

Test codes:

```
>>> meow_meow = Tamagotchi("meow meow")
>>> meow_meow.teach("meow")
>>> meow_meow.play()
'meow meow says meow'
>>> meow_meow.teach("purr")
>>> meow_meow.teach("meow")
>>> meow_meow.play()
'meow meow says meow and purr'
>>> meow_meow.kill()
'meow_meow killed'
>>> meow_meow.teach("hello")
'meow meow is pining for the fjords'
>>> meow_meow.play()
'meow meow is pining for the fjords'
```

Whats wrong with my code? i didn't get the result i want for meow_meow.play()

Comment: What are the results you are expecting?

Comment: It's in the test code: 'meow meow says meow'

Answer (score 2):

That `self` variable that is passed in the class method refers to the instance of the `Tamagotchi`.  To avoid telling you how to do your homework, consider the `__init__` function where you assign the name to the instance, so

```
>>> meow_meow = Tamagotchi("meow meow")
>>> meow_meow.name
'meow meow'
```

Now teaching a `Tamagotchi` a word means that it should say the new word, provided it's not already there.  You have the right idea in your `teach` method, but you're not assigning it to the instance, so it's lost on future calls.  As well, for your play method, `words` isn't defined in the method, so it will fail.  Consider keeping track of words in `teach`, then format them in `play`.

**Edit**:
Since OP said this was too vague.  This example will use a parrot.  My parrot is pretty dumb though, he only repeats the last thing I say, so lets implement my parrot in code

```
class Parrot():
    def __init__(self, name):
        # self is passed implicitly for new instances of the class
        # it refers to the instance itself
        self.name = name
        self.words = ""

    def hear(self, words):
        # My parrot overhears me saying a sentence
        # 'self', the first argument passed, refers to the instance of my parrot
        # I overwrite the instance value of 'words' (self.words) by assigning the
        # new words that were passed as the instance words value
        self.words = words

    def speak(self):
        # I return whatever the instance 'words' variable contains
        return self.words
```

Now lets run through a session of me and my bird talking.  I'll name here Gladys.

```
>>> my_parrot = Parrot("Gladys")
>>> my_parrot.speak()
""
>>> my_parrot.hear("Gladys, what is your name?")
>>> my_parrot.speak()
"Gladys, what is your name?"
>>> my_parrot.hear("No, Gladys, what is your name?")
>>> my_parrot.speak()
"No, Gladys, what is your name?"
>>> my_parrot.hear("No, you are Gladys.")
>>> my_parrot.speak()
"No, you are Gladys."
```

Comment: Right..i know all these...your guidelines are too vague.

Comment: Updated the answer for you OP