# Obj Orientation on variable number of string input

Tags: python

```
class Tamagotchi(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def teach(self,word):
        if word == "hello":
            return (self.name + "is pining for the fjord")
        else:
            return (self.name + "says" + word)
    def play(self):
        return self.teach("and")
```

This is my code

However I am not able to get my desired output

```
meow_meow = Tamagotchi("meow meow")


meow_meow.teach("meow")
print(meow_meow.play()) #'meow meow says meow'

meow_meow.teach("purr")
meow_meow.teach("meow")
print(meow_meow.play()) #'meow meow says meow and purr'

print(meow_meow.teach("hello")) #'meow meow is pining for the fjords'

print(meow_meow.play()) #'meow meow is pining for the fjords'
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Your title is completely unrelated to the material actually in your question; I only know what you're talking about because I read [another question on the same topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038666/object-oriented-programming-with-tamagotchi-class). Note that `teach` *doesn't* `print` anything in your example, and you have missed out `kill` from your example, so it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of problems with what you have now:

1. `'meow meow is pining for the fjords'` is the response to *every method call* after `meow_meow.kill()` is called, not just to `meow_meow.teach("hello")`. Indeed, before you `kill`, `teach("hello")` shouldn't `return` *anything*.
2. But you haven't implemented (or mentioned!) `kill`.
3. `'meow meow says meow'` is the response to `meow_meow.play()`, *not* to `meow_meow.teach(...)`, which (again) shouldn't `return` anything.
4. You don't check in `teach` whether the `word` is already known or not, or allow for multiple words to be passed (which I think is what your title refers to).
5. `teach` also doesn't store the words the `Tamagotchi` has already been taught.
6. `play` teaches the `Tamagotchi` the word `'and'`, which is useless - it ought to work through *all words already taught*, putting `'and'` between each one.

I suggest you look at the following:

- [String methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)
- [The `list`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)
- [Arbitrary argument lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)

To point you in the right direction, here's a start:

```
class Tamagotchi(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.words = []
        self.alive = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not storing `word` and you need to be:

```
class Tamagotchi(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.word = name

    def teach(self,word):
        self.word = word
        return self.say()

    def say(self):
        if self.word == "hello":
            return (self.name + " is pining for the fjord")
        else:
            return (self.name + " says " + self.word)

    def play(self):
        return self.teach("and")
```

Notice how teach() just memorizes the word.  Then say() regurgitates it.  This will work for one word at a time.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that meow_meow.play() is equivalent to meow_meow.teach(x)  And you are not storing  the taught words. So the simplest thing to do is to replace

```
print(meow_meow.play())
```

with this:

```
meow_meow.teach("meow and purr")
```

You should also add spaces to the output.

```
return (self.name + " says " + word)
```

Comment: Isn't that hard coding ? What if i don't want "meow" instead I want "mo and purr" ?

Comment: It was just an example. Replace "meow and purr" with whatever you want. Right now you have play set up to return teach with a hardcoded value. So you already have hardcoded values. So I'm saying that you should just remove .play and use .teach()

Comment: @midfield99 I suggest you look at the linked question - the OP is a long way from working code

Comment: You can store the word with teach and have play regurgitate it, as in the other example. But as mentioned that only stores one word, so .play() won't return multiple words, which is what your example shows you want.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. I didn't see that link when I posted the answer.

Comment: @midfield99 no problem, the question is at fault here!